# nvidia-settings not able to save my configuration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, monitor

(This is a continuation of thread: [Installing nvidia driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150825/installing-nvidia-driver)).

I am able to detect and configure an external monitor using nvidia-settings program.  However, when I try to save my configuration, nvidia-settings complains that it can't save to xorg.conf.

It states that: "Default Device" must have a Driver line.

Now, I ran nvidia-settings using sudo, so this isn't a permissions problem.  Here's my file (I am typing it by hand, since my ubuntu laptop has all sorts of config errors, created by my overconfident self.  :)

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Default Device"
    Option   "NoLogo"   "True"
EndSection
```

Do I just add a driver line?  And what should it look like?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run nvidia-settings as root

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

You can then save your setting.

When saving, unselect the "Merge with existing file" box

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Anyways, from the main window, I highlight the 'X Server Display Configuration', then on the right pane I press 'Save to X Configuration File'.  

After doing so, a box pops up stating that it can't be done.  The erroe message is 'Failed to parse existing X config file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'!'.  

I did use the exact command that you suggested, gksu nvidia-settings.


Anyways, after clicking 'OK' on the pop up error window, I get the screen shot that you have displayed, without the graphics on save and cancel.  However, the merge option is faded.  What to do? thx

Answer (score 0):

The Driver line should look like this:

```
Driver         "nvidia"
```

You can just put it right under the identifier. For others with this issue, the xorg.conf file is located at /etc/X11/xorg.conf I think you will need to reboot after making this change.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get beyond my initial problem.  Now, when I reboot, I see that I can use my external monitor along with my laptop display.  However, when I login, I get an error box that pops up:

Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors.  Under that, is more details:

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:  Trying modes for CRTC 351.

CRTC 351: trying mode 3360x1080@50HZ with output at 1440x900@50Hz (pass 0)

There is an identical message with (pass 1).  But, everything seems to work.  Any suggestions?  I'll play with the configs.

Comment: Oh, one weird thing, my external monitor does not have 3360x1080 resolution.  I don't know where it got that.  My resolution is 1920x1080 for the external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing execute permissions on /usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-polkit for your user. Once I did this I was able to save my config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).